# Why do we need PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Why do we need PriorityQueue if if have LinkedList. I can sort queue with    LinkedList faster than with PriorityQueue. e.g.

```
Queue list = new PriorityQueue();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("2");
    while(list.size() > 0) {
        String s = list.poll().toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

I believe this code works too long, cause each time I add element it will sort elements.
but if I will use next code:

```
Queue list = new LinkedList();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("2");
    List lst = (List)list;
    Collections.sort(lst);
    while(list.size() > 0) {
        String s = list.poll().toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

I think this code will sort only once and it will be faster that using PriorityQueue. So, I can once sort my LinkedList once, before using it, in any case and it will work faster. And even if it sort the same time I don't really need PriorityQueue, we really don't need this class. Am I wrong?

Comment: Its like the exact opposite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878118/java-priorityqueue-vs-sorted-linkedlist

Comment: In my experience, a `PriorityQueue` is Java's implementation of a Heap structure.

Comment: @bradimus `java.util` actually has really terrible object-oriented practices. Many of the classes violate the Liskov substitution principle for convenience.

Comment: What would you do if you needed to add more elements in the middle?

Comment: Louis, I will use LinkedList, cause PriorityQueue can't do this, case it just Queue, it can add only at the end of the queue and then sort queue, plus I need sort each time I add something. So LinkedLIst better in any way.